# Stratified splitting train/test - H2O

Tags: machine-learning, h2o

I use H2O to build and compare models but I wanted to know if there is a feature that allows me to split the data into train and test in a stratified way?

I know that for cross validation the option fold_assignment exist and I use it.

My question is more on the manipulation of the data and when it needs to be split before any model is built.

I had a look a this [page](http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-munging/splitting-datasets.html) but it does not specify if stratified splitting is done for classification.

Maybe for classification problems it is implicit and the stratified splitting is always achieved?

Answer (score 0):

Split the data into Train/Test/Validation with Train having 70% and test and validation 15% each

```
train,test,valid = prostate_df.split_frame(ratios=(.7, .15))
```